# parse pbtxt(tensorflow) like xml etree in python

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I am working with TensorFlow graph in pbtxt format.

pbtxt file was generated from tf object detection API and I need to parse it like xml etree. How can I do this?

The .pbtxt the result of a freeze_graph

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved. You can use:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from google.protobuf import text_format

with open('graph.pbtxt') as f:
    txt = f.read()

graph_def = text_format.Parse(txt, tf.GraphDef())

for node in graph_def.node:
    if node.name == "bla-bla":
        #TODO
```

For more information: [here](http://tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers)

Comment: Sorry but it gives me this error google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 1:1 : Message type "tensorflow.GraphDef" has no field named "item".

Comment: Is there an alternative to `tf.GraphDef` that works for .config files in pbtxt format? For example: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs

Comment: Use pipeline.proto to generate the protocol message in python and then import TrainEvalPipelineConfig from it. Quick example:
    
    `from pathlib import Path
    from google.protobuf import text_format
    from pipeline_pb2 import TrainEvalPipelineConfig

    with open(str(Path.cwd() / "config.pbtxt")) as f:
        config = f.read()
        protobuf = TrainEvalPipelineConfig()
        config = text_format.Parse(names, protobuf)

    print(config)`